# How to avoid formula injection while keeping cell value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to avoid formula injection while keeping cell value in Javascript.

Is there a way to keep the value escaped in the formula editor, but show the correct value, without the leading single quote, in the cell?

I export excell and trying to avoid formula by changing the cell value.

Below is my code.

```
var cellValue = cell.value;
if( cellValue != null && "=-+@".indexOf(cellValue.charAt(0)) >= 0 ) {
     cell.value= "'"+cell.value;
}
```

Here I am trying to append single quote while exporting. But afetr export the single quote valeis still presentt in my cell.

Comment: I posted the answer below, but if it does not suit you, then could you indicate which library you are using so that I can fix it

Comment: @UDID, are you using CSV file or xlsx file?

Comment: @DevMaster I am using xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

try adding **=** before the cell value and value should be enclosed within double quotes.

Ex: Cell value =>   **=A1+B1**

escaping string should be **="=A1+B1"**

code looks as below.

```js
var cellValue = cell.value;
if( cellValue != null && "=-+@".indexOf(cellValue.charAt(0)) >= 0 ) {
     cell.value= "=\""+cell.value+"\"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getValue = (cellValue) => { 
  if( cellValue !== null && cellValue.match(/^[=@+-]/) ) {
     return `"${cellValue}"`; // wrap in ""
  } 
  return cellValue; // as is
}

console.log(getValue('=A1+B1'))    // "=A1+B1"
console.log(getValue('@A1+B1'))    // "@A1+B1"
console.log(getValue('+A1+B1'))    // "+A1+B1"
console.log(getValue('-A1+B1'))    // "-A1+B1"
console.log(getValue('something')) // something
```